# Append a value in View Swift 5

Tags: swift

I have a variable called UYEADST. I add the data I have drawn from the database to this variable. There is no problem adding the data to the variable and pulling the data, there is no problem that I output with print. But when I pull the variable UYEADST in viewDidLoad, it appears to be a null value. What is the problem?

```
class profilViewController: UIViewController {

    var bilgiUYEADST : String = ""

    func bilgiUYEAD(){
                let client = SQLClient.sharedInstance()!
                       client.connect("...", username: "...", password: "...", database: "...") { success in
                       client.execute("SELECT form_adsoyad FROM uzaktanptomg_db.omg_user.ie_form WHERE form_no LIKE '\(self.form_no)'", completion: { (_ results: ([Any]?)) in
                                  for table in results as! [[[String:AnyObject]]] {
                                   for row in table {
                                   for (_, value) in row {
                                     if let intVal = value as? String {
                                        self.bilgiUYEADST = intVal
                                       }} }}
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()) { [weak self] in
 } client.disconnect() }) } }

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if passwordKeychain != nil {
            form_no = passwordKeychain!
        }

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        bilgiUYEAD()
        emailLabel.text = (bilgiUYEADST)
        }
```

Comment: Try the same thing in `viewWillApper`.

Comment: This may be because the code is running asynchronously.

Comment: What would you suggest me to do? @chirag90

Comment: one way of doing it is by adding a completion block to your `bilgiUYEAD` function and then try and do rest of your code in completion block.

Comment: You should add it as answer below.